# How can I substring a handlebar expression using a custom helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I wanted to get a substring of my handlebar expression using a helper like this:

```
 helpers:{
    calc: function(value, start , end){
        return value.substring(start , end)
    }
 }
```

But it returned an error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of null`

And this is from my views page

`<td>{{calc this.first_quarter 1 4}}</td>`

Comment: This can be resolved with some troubleshooting on your part. Your helper function is being called (which is good), but `value` is `null`. This could be because `this.first_quarter` is null, or something else. Stick `console.log(value)` before `return value.substring()` and confirm `value` is `null`. Then do the same where you initialise/update `this.first_quarter` and you'll narrow down possibilities. Alternatively, share your code where you initialise/update `first_quarter`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You are correct my value is null and I've just fixed my problem thank you again!